# Implementing a Sobel filter with SVG filters

Tags: svg, svg-filters

At first glance I thought this would be pretty straight forward. Google found [this](http://www.getcodesamples.com/src/8E9C32FE/62F63020) with the following bit of code, but it's not a real sobel filter.

```
<filter id="edge">
<feColorMatrix type="luminanceToAlpha" />
<feConvolveMatrix order="3" kernelMatrix="-1 -2 -1 0 0 0 1 2 1" />
<feConvolveMatrix order="3" kernelMatrix="-1 -2 -1 0 0 0 1 2 1" />
</filter>
```

Following the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) I would need a way to find the distances between two `feConvolveMatrix` results. I can square and add them by compositing, but there doesn't seem to be any way to get a square root operator. Is it possible?

I've added my current solution below but it doesn't quite match the reference.

Answer (score 1):

[`feDiffuseLighting`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#feDiffuseLightingElement) actually computes a sobel filter to generate a normal. I've thrown the following together, which extracts RGB into three white images each with R, G and B as alpha for the heightmap. The `z` component of the normal (which is `1 - sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2)`) is then extracted with a directional light positioned above the image. Finally it's inverted (to obtain just `sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2)`) and all three channels are combined.

I'm not too sure about `color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"` the images is incredibly dark so I've set `surfaceScale="8.0"` to give higher variation in the deltas. It still doesn't look quite like the reference but it's close. Also, for whatever reason the filter expands outwards to cover other parts of the HTML (*EDIT:* see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24420004/1888983)).

Test images from [this page](http://www.roborealm.com/help/Sobel.php):
[image][image]

```css
.sobelme {
  -webkit-filter: url('#sobel');
  -moz-filter: url('#sobel');
  -ms-filter: url('#sobel');
  -o-filter: url('#sobel');
  filter: url('#sobel');
}
```

```html
<img class="sobelme" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/sld5Y.png" />
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wq077.png" />

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height="0">
  <filter id="sobel" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="SourceGraphic" result="RA" values="0 0 0 0 1
          0 0 0 0 1
          0 0 0 0 1
          1 0 0 0 0"></feColorMatrix>
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="SourceGraphic" result="GA" values="0 0 0 0 1
          0 0 0 0 1
          0 0 0 0 1
          0 1 0 0 0"></feColorMatrix>
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="SourceGraphic" result="BA" values="0 0 0 0 1
          0 0 0 0 1
          0 0 0 0 1
          0 0 1 0 0"></feColorMatrix>
    <feDiffuseLighting in="RA" result="R" surfaceScale="8.0">
      <feDistantLight elevation="90"></feDistantLight>
    </feDiffuseLighting>
    <feDiffuseLighting in="GA" result="G" surfaceScale="8.0">
      <feDistantLight elevation="90"></feDistantLight>
    </feDiffuseLighting>
    <feDiffuseLighting in="BA" result="B" surfaceScale="8.0">
      <feDistantLight elevation="90"></feDistantLight>
    </feDiffuseLighting>
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="R" result="RS" values="-1 0 0 0 1
          0 0 0 0 0
          0 0 0 0 0
          0 0 0 0 1"></feColorMatrix>
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="G" result="GS" values="0 0 0 0 0
          0 -1 0 0 1
          0 0 0 0 0
          0 0 0 0 1"></feColorMatrix>
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="B" result="BS" values="0 0 0 0 0
          0 0 0 0 0
          0 0 -1 0 1
          0 0 0 0 1"></feColorMatrix>
    <feComposite in="RS" in2="GS" result="RSGS" operator="arithmetic" k1="0" k2="1" k3="1" k4="0"></feComposite>
    <feComposite in="RSGS" in2="BS" operator="arithmetic" k1="0" k2="1" k3="1" k4="0"></feComposite>
  </filter>
</svg>
```

*UPDATE:*

The test image is an approximation which ignores the distance between horizontal and vertical deltas and simply sums them. The Sobel filter for the normal calculation with the above `feDiffuseLighting` is normalized, which is why the scale by 8 is needed. Simply adding the absolute values of the horizontal and vertical deltas, without the `sqrt()` similarly to [@MichaelMullany's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35097411/1888983), can be achieved as follows. An advantage is the annoying expansion of the filter outside the borders doesn't happen. `color-interpolation-filters` is necessary otherwise a gamma is applied, giving a strange result. It still doesn't quite match the test image but it's closer and simpler.

```css
.sobelme {
  -webkit-filter: url('#sobel');
  -moz-filter: url('#sobel');
  -ms-filter: url('#sobel');
  -o-filter: url('#sobel');
  filter: url('#sobel');
}
```

```html
<img class="sobelme" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/sld5Y.png" />
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wq077.png" />

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height="0">
  <filter id="sobel" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    <feConvolveMatrix in="SourceGraphic" order="3" preserveAlpha="true" kernelMatrix="-1 -2 -1
0 0 0
1 2 1 " result="VP" />
    <feConvolveMatrix in="SourceGraphic" order="3" preserveAlpha="true" kernelMatrix="1 2 1
0 0 0
-1 -2 -1 " result="VN" />
    <feConvolveMatrix in="SourceGraphic" order="3" preserveAlpha="true" kernelMatrix="-1 0 1
-2 0 2
-1 0 1 " result="HP" />
    <feConvolveMatrix in="SourceGraphic" order="3" preserveAlpha="true" kernelMatrix="1 0 -1
2 0 -2
1 0 -1 " result="HN" />
    <feComposite operator="arithmetic" in="VN" in2="VP" k2="1" k3="1" result="V" />
    <feComposite operator="arithmetic" in="HN" in2="HP" k2="1" k3="1" result="H" />
    <!-- <feComposite operator="arithmetic" in="V" in2="H" k2="1" k3="1" /> -->
    <feBlend mode="lighten" in="H" in2="V" />
  </filter>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

That sample code is wrong. Here is a conventional Sobel using convolution. It separates out the channels and converts them to alpha, runs edge detection, recolors them back to RGB and adds the channels back together. To get to the exact reference result, it looks like they add thresholding - which can you can do using feComponentTransfer.

```html
<svg width="600px" height="800px" >

<defs>
<filter id="sobel" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
    <!-- convert source image to luminance map-->
    <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 1 
                                         0 0 0 0 1 
                                         0 0 0 0 1 
                                         1 0 0 0 0" result="RChan" />
  
      <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 1 
                                         0 0 0 0 1 
                                         0 0 0 0 1 
                                         0 1 0 0 0" result="GChan" />
  
  
      <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 1 
                                         0 0 0 0 1 
                                         0 0 0 0 1 
                                         0 0 1 0 0" result="BChan" />
  
    <!-- sobel edge detection-->

  
    <feConvolveMatrix in="RChan" order="3" kernelMatrix="-1 -2 -1  
                                               0 0 0  
                                               1 2 1 "
                 
                   result="Rhor" />
  
    <feConvolveMatrix in="RChan" order="3" kernelMatrix="-1 0 1  
                                                                 -2 0 2 
                                                                 -1 0 1"  result="Rver"  />
  
   <feComposite operator="arithmetic" k2="1" k3="1" in="Rhor" in2="Rver" />
   <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 1 0
                                    0 0 0 0 0 
                                    0 0 0 0 0 
                                    0 0 0 0 1" result="rededge"/>

  
   <feConvolveMatrix in="GChan" order="3" kernelMatrix="-1 -2 -1  
                                               0 0 0  
                                               1 2 1"
                   result="Ghor" />
  
    <feConvolveMatrix in="GChan" order="3" kernelMatrix="-1 0 1 
                                                         -2 0 2 
                                                         -1 0 1"  result="Gver"  />
  
   <feComposite operator="arithmetic" k2="1" k3="1" in="Ghor" in2="Gver" />
   <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0
                                    0 0 0 1 0 
                                    0 0 0 0 0 
                                    0 0 0 0 1" result="greenedge"/>
  

   <feConvolveMatrix in="BChan" order="3" kernelMatrix="-1 -2 -1  
                                               0 0 0  
                                               1 2 1 " result="Bhor" />
  
    <feConvolveMatrix in="BChan" order="3" kernelMatrix="-1 0 1  
                                                                 -2 0 2 
                                                                 -1 0 1"  result="Bver"  />
  
   <feComposite operator="arithmetic" k2="1" k3="1" in="Bhor" in2="Bver"/>
   <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0
                                    0 0 0 0 0 
                                    0 0 0 1 0 
                                    0 0 0 0 1" result="blueedge"/>

  <feComposite operator="arithmetic" in="blueedge" in2="rededge" k2="1" k3="1"/>
  <feComposite operator="arithmetic" in2="greenedge" k2="1" k3="1" result="finaledges"/>
  
  <feFlood flood-color="black" result="black"/>
  <feComposite operator="over" in="finaledges"/>
  </filter>
  
  </defs>

<image width="400" height="300" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" xlink:href="http://www.roborealm.com/help/Sobel_src.jpg"/>
  
  <image filter="url(#sobel)" y="400" width="400" height="300" xlink:href="http://www.roborealm.com/help/Sobel_src.jpg"/>
  
</svg>
```